# iTunes Album Artwork

Tags: itunes, album-art

I listen to a lot of indie music and so have a lot of songs that were released as singles and have their own album artwork. I always use the list view that displays album artwork on the left. I also combine a lot of the singles that I have into albums which I use to sort them. iTunes seems to randomly choose one of their artworks to display as the artwork for the entire album, is there any way I could set one artwork for the album and also have separate artwork for the individual songs?

Answer (score 2):

No, iTunes and related apps use the artwork from the initial track of each album. Yes, it is frustrating. And no, it is not worth retagging your songs to pretend each of the tracks is its own album.

I asked what is essentially the same question over here:

https://superuser.com/questions/11081/how-can-i-force-front-row-to-show-me-single-artwork-instead-of-album-artwork

In case you want to ask Apple to add this feature, here is the feedback page for iTunes:
http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html

Comment: that's interesting, because on my iphone it displays the correct artwork for the individual song in the background.

Comment: @adrusi yes, until you turn your phone sideways